# Discord.js How to let bot don't delete his message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i created channel for people want join clan or leave by typing commands, and this channel only accept word **(clan join and clan leave ) and bot message.** anything else bot delete user message, only i don't want from bot delete his message.

```js
const botID = 'bot ID';
bot.on('message', message => {
    if(message.channel.id === 'channel ID'){
    if(!(
    message.content === prefix+'clan join'||
    message.content === prefix+'clan leave'||
    message.content === message.member(bot.user.id) === botID)) return message.delete(0);
    }
```

All I want is bot doesn't delete his messages.Thanks

Comment: Sorry my english not good.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the error with your code? What is the problem?

Comment: my code delete my bot message but i don't want him to delete his message only delete users message

Comment: is there any reason you have 2 sets of `===` in the following line of code:  `message.content === message.member(bot.user.id) === botID)` ?

Comment: yes that is mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `message.member()` does not exist.

Here is what worked for me:

```
bot.on("message", message => {

 if (message.channel.id === "channel ID") {

  if (
   message.content !== prefix+'clan join' 
   && message.content !== prefix+'clan leave'
   && message.author.id !== bot.user.id)
  ) return message.delete();

 }

})
```

Comment: Make sure to catch rejected promises.